# Angular 6 - How to register different routes based on the value of a variable

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-routing

I am trying to register a different set of routes based on which region I am running my application in.

That region is in a JSON file that is dynamically replaced after the application is built, and I load it in the following way, in my `environment.ts` file:

```
import config from '../assets/config/config.json';

export const environment = config;
```

The environment variable then contains something like that:

```
{
    "stage": "dev",
    "endpoint": "<backend endpoint>",
    "realm": "<US or CA>"
}
```

In one of my modules I then load routes, but I want a different set based on the region, so I have the following code:

```
export const routes: Routes = {
    US: [
        { path: 'my-route', component: MyComponentForUS }
    ],
    CA: [
        { path: 'my-route', component: MyComponentForCA }
    ]
}[environment.realm];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(routes)
    ],
    declarations: [
        MyComponentForUS,
        MyComponentForCA
    ]
})
export class MyModule {
}
```

This is working perfectly fine when I run the application with `ng serve` or `ng serve --aot`, but when I try to build the application for production use with `ng build --prod --aot`, I consistently get the following error:

```
ERROR in Cannot read property 'loadChildren' of null
```

I am fine with changing the way I load the routes based on the environment, but everything I tried so far gave a similar result.

Thanks

Comment: Go through this link - https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3841 . Hope it helps!

Comment: @KrunalShah unfortunately it doesn't, I have already looked at it, but it is not the same root cause, I'm not using `default`, basically I already have the solution that worked for him, but still have the error...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried switching the stage from "dev" to "build"?

Comment: The stage here isn't used in the build process, it's just another variable that we use in the application but it's not related to angular AFAIK.

Comment: Have you tried defining one "RoutesForCA" and one "RoutesForUS" variable. Then in the MyModule ctor read the config and inject the routes in the router module?

Comment: I did and it kinda works but the pages don't work if you access them directly from the URL, you have to add all the components to the entryComponents array and the prefixes set by parent modules for the routes aren't saved, so it's not really usable.

Comment: If you have built the CA built you should not be able to access the US routes. With this setup you have to choose one or the other. If you want to be able to choose from both I would recommend a global variable that you can set dinamically on the browser and do it through the ctor method I told you in the last comment.

Comment: Yes I don't want to have both set of routes accessible, only the one corresponding to the `environment.realm` value, and while your previous comment makes it work, I think it's not really usable in my case because of the downsides I mentioned.

Comment: I hope you find your answer bro